# css :hover not working on div after animating opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-animations

I am trying to change the color on hover of a button inside a pop-up box. I display the pop up box by animating the opacity from .001 to 1. Nothing inside the pop-up box responds to the css :hover rules. Why is :hover not working anywhere in the div?

CSS:

```
.privacyDetails {
  height: 80vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 4fr 2fr;
  opacity: 0.001;
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.privacyDetailsBox {
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 40vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: rgb(254, 130, 235);
  border: 1px solid rgb(254, 130, 235);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 10fr;
}

.privacyDetailsText {
  padding: 7%;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.privacyDetailsClose {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.privacyDetailsClose:hover {
  color: rgb(254, 130, 235);
  background-color: white;
}
```

JS(react):

```
  function showPrivacyDetails() {
    privacyDetailsRef.current.style.opacity = "1";
    contentRef.current.style.opacity = ".05";
  }
```

Comment: please add your HTML.

Comment: The only `:hover` rule I see in your css is for `.privasyDetailsClose`, which I guess is the close button of the modal. no any rule for the modal itself (`.privacyDetailsBox`)